# What is that "." in size dimenson of NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

On http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_integers.html#numpy.random.random_integers

```
np.random.random_integers(5, size=(3.,2.))
```

I did not understand the "." that comes after "3"

I tried

```
np.random.random_integers(5, size=(3,2))
```

and it seems to be exact same as one with "."

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`3.` is just short for `3.0`, i.e. the same as `float(3)`.

```
>>> 3.
=> 3.0
>>> type(3.)
=> float
```

Apparently, `random_integers` accepts the `size` argument as floats *or* as ints, thus passing `(3.,2.)` is equivalent to `(3,2)`.

Comment: Accept the size as float but just consider the `int` part!